# Applying boosting to predictions from a Random Forest

Tags: classification, random-forest, boosting

I have a class of datasets for a binary classification problem where it is known that Random Forest performs poorly compared with GBM or FFNN, rarely adding anything to an ensemble. I've had an idea to use a best performing RF model as the first stage in a GBM. So the initial probability of 'TRUE' would be given by the RF, but subsequent incremental boosting models would be produced according to the standard GBM approach.

A priori, does this seem sensible? I am working in R, using H2O to produce both models. My instinct is to get my first stage RF model from the H2O function, and build the GBM myself, running it in base R. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems an interesting idea to me.  Wouldn't you rather be running the GBM on the residuals of the RF?   In that case, you could run the GBM in H20 as well.   If you wanted to treat the RF as a substitute for the first stage of the GBM, you'd have to apply the learning rate to the RF estimates, and, for small learning rates (e.g., 0.1 or smaller), that means the RF would add little value, or so it seems to me.

Comment: +1 @jbowman comment. One more: if you are feeding probabilities to the GBM you might want to ensure they are well-calibrated. Maybe using a GLM/GAM would be more informative to RF where intrinsically the probabilities are calculated by the proportions directly.

Comment: (I just undid my upvote by accident. *silent facepalm*)